# how to animate snackbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Animated Snackbar'),
        ),
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void showAnimatedSnackbar(BuildContext context) {
    final animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: Scaffold.of(context),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 650),
    );

    final animation = Tween(begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController, curve: Curves.decelerate));

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
  //        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0), // Customize the border radius
  // ), 
        content: SlideTransition(
          position: animation,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 8,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0), 
                ),
                // height: 70,
                // width: 200,
               
                child: Center(child: Text('This is an animated Snackbar!'))),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    animationController.forward();
  }

  void callShowSnackbar(BuildContext context) {
    showAnimatedSnackbar(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showAnimatedSnackbar(context);
            },
            child: Text('Show Animated Snackbar'),
          ),
          // ElevatedButton(
          //   onPressed: () {
          //     callShowSnackbar(context);
          //   },
          //   child: Text('Call from Another Function'),
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I want to animate this "snackbar". While the "snackbar" is dismissing, you can see that the animation isn't working. I want an ease-out or any other animation when it dismisses. The snackbar is coming with an animation, Can anyone fix it? Thanks in advance..[image]**
*(i want the snackbar animation like instagram has)*

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar

Answer (score 0):

maybe these extension can solve your problem;

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_snack_bar or
https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_snackbar_content

Even if it doesn't meet your expectations, you can still dive into the their source code and use the necessary animations.

Comment: Im a beginner and i just wanna add reverse animation

Comment: have you checked these extensions?